# Why can't I subtract 3 times?

Tags: perl, time

**Just updated the OP because I had done a bad typo.**

This script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Piece;

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime( '10:15', '%H:%M' );
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime( '17:30', '%H:%M' );
my $t3 = Time::Piece->strptime( '7:24', '%H:%M' );

my $t = $t2 - $t1 - $t3;

print int($t->hours) . ":" . $t->minutes%60 . "\n";
```

will output

```
Can't use non Seconds object in operator overload at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/Time/Seconds.pm line 65.
```

The correct answer is `-0:09` ie. 0 hours and -9 minutes.

**Question**

How can I subtract the 3 times?
Can `Time::Piece` or `Time::Seconds` do the `int` and modulus for me, so I don't have to?

Comment: `$3` and `$t3` are not the same thing.

Comment: Very nicely spotted, which explains why I didn't get the original error I wanted to reproduce. Now the script produces the "right" error.

Comment: Are those time-of-days or durations? What are you trying to do (in English words)? Is $t2 sometime kind of total of three duration (`$t`, `$t1` and `$t3`) and you're trying to get the third duration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't subtract a time from a duration. For instance, nine minutes minus one o'clock is meaningless.

Here you have `$t1` equals `10:15am`, and `$t2` equals `17:30` or `5:30pm`. So `$t2 - $t1` is the time between them, or 7.25 hours.

Now you are trying to subtract `$t3`, which is `7:24am`, from that result. But 7.25 hours minus 7:24am is a duration minus a time of day, and can't be done. That is why you get the message
`Can't use non Seconds object` because you're trying to subtract a `Time::Piece` object (a time of day) from a `Time::Seconds` object (a duration).

---

**Update**

If you are working in *durations* then you need the `Time::Seconds` module throughout like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Seconds;

my $t1 = Time::Seconds->new(10 * ONE_HOUR + 15 * ONE_MINUTE); # 10:15
my $t2 = Time::Seconds->new(17 * ONE_HOUR + 30 * ONE_MINUTE); # 17:30
my $t3 = Time::Seconds->new( 7 * ONE_HOUR + 24 * ONE_MINUTE); #  7:24

my $t = $t2 - $t1 - $t3;

print $t->minutes, "\n";
```

**output**

```
-9
```

or perhaps you would prefer to subtract midnight `00:00` from your `Time::Piece` objects, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

use constant MIDNIGHT => Time::Piece->strptime('00:00', '%H:%M');

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime( '10:15', '%H:%M' );
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime( '17:30', '%H:%M' );
my $t3 = Time::Piece->strptime(  '7:24', '%H:%M' );

$_ -= MIDNIGHT for $t1, $t2, $t3;

my $t = $t2 - $t1 - $t3;

print $t->minutes;
```

which also outputs `-9`.

**Note** that you won't get what you want using the modulus as in `$t->minutes % 60` because `-9 % 60` is `51` minutes.

---

**Update 2**

Another option would be to write a helper routine that uses either of the previous options. This example has the subroutine `new_duration`, which uses `Time::Piece->strptime` to parse the string passed in and then subtract midnight before handing back the resulting `Time::Seconds` object.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

use constant MIDNIGHT => Time::Piece->strptime('00:00', '%H:%M');

my $t1 = new_duration('10:15');
my $t2 = new_duration('17:30');
my $t3 = new_duration( '7:24');

my $t = $t2 - $t1 - $t3;

print $t->minutes;

sub new_duration {
  Time::Piece->strptime(shift, '%H:%M') - MIDNIGHT;
}
```

**output**

```
-9
```

Comment: Then is there some simple way to convert `'10:15'` to `Time::Seconds->new(10*3600+15*60)`?

Comment: Is subtracting midnight correct on a day with a Daylight Savings shift?  Also, what if my script runs past midnight or for several days?

Comment: `Time::Piece` ignores daylight saving, and the problem with intervals that cross midnight boundaries exists with your original code. If you can only specify times then the differences can never be more than 24 hours.

Comment: @aschepler: I think you should post a new question with your *real* problem, instead of changing your question bit by bit.

Comment: I don't have any original code or real problem.  Just trying to learn what I can and help make sure the answer is accurate and useful.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence:

```
my $t = $t2 - $t1 - $3;
```

should be

```
my $t = $t2 - $t1 - $t3;
```

Comment: Yes, I had done a bad typo in the script, but when corrected, I get an error message when subtracting the 3 times.

Comment: `$t2 - $t1` is a `Time::Seconds` object from which you can't subtract another `Time::Piece` object, so your answer does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

`$t2 - $t1` returns a `Time::Seconds` object on which the `-` operator is not defined.